# How can I extract or preg_replace chinese characters in a string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am currently have a list of string like this

```
蘋果，香蕉，橙。
榴蓮, 啤梨
鳳爪，排骨，雞排
24個男，2個女，30個老人
```

What I want to do is just explode all chinese and alphanumeric character from these strings.
How can I replace all special characters like `，` `,` `。`  `/` `"` and spaces with `-` or `_`

then extract all chinese character with `explode()` like `$str = explode("-",$str);` or `$str = explode("_",$str);` ?

I am currently have a RegEx like this

```
 if(/^\S[\u0391-\uFFE5 \w]+\S$/.test(value)).....
```

And I modified it into

```
 $str = preg_replace("/^\S[\x{0391}-\x{FFE5} \w]+\s+\S$/u", "-", $str);
```

but it seems it didn't work...

the online exampls: https://www.regex101.com/r/qR8aA6/1

EDIT : my expected output(for the first sting):

firstly it should be replaced into

`蘋果-香蕉-橙-` or `蘋果_香蕉_橙_`

then I can use `$str = explode("-",$str);` to make them finally become:

```
Array
    (
     [0] => 蘋果
     [1] => 香蕉
     [2] => 橙
     )
```

Comment: What's your expected output? Did you want to replace `\n` with `-` ?

Comment: what is your final goal? why do you need to replace characters?

Comment: instead of replacing with `-`, you could directly split the input according to `[^\p{L}\p{N}\n]+` regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
$txt = <<<EOT
蘋果，香蕉，橙。
榴蓮, 啤梨
鳳爪，排骨，雞排
24個男，2個女，30個老人
EOT;
echo preg_replace('~[^\p{L}\p{N}\n]+~u', '-', $txt);
```

**Output:**

```
蘋果-香蕉-橙-
榴蓮-啤梨
鳳爪-排骨-雞排
24個男-2個女-30個老人
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/qR8aA6/2)

**Explanation:**

- `\p{L}` Matches any kind of letter from any language.
- `\p{N}` matches any kind of numeric character in any script.
- `\n` Matches a newline character.
- By putting all inside a negated character class will do the opposite operation.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer. But one more thing, is it possible to NOT replacing just for `/` and a `,` between alphanumeric chars (such as G,F , A,B , 9,000) ?

Comment: `\B,\B` won't match the commas which are inbetween the alphanumeric characters. https://regex101.com/r/eG7cI3/1