# PHP SEO URL accept chinese word

Tags: php, seo

I have below function for SEO parameter, somehow when url contains characters other than alphabet, it will strip off and page will direct to 404, some of my url will contains Chinese character, how can it be accepted Chinese character instead?

```
public function seoUrl($string)
{
    //Lower case everything
    $string = strtolower($string);
    //Make alphanumeric (removes all other characters)
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);
    //Clean up multiple dashes or whitespaces
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
    //Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/28357638/3785693

Comment: @LFlare, that link is helpful but not all character is showing accurate, such as `加里曼丹` become `�-釜曼丹`